# bash: jest: command not found

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, backend

- I know I installed jest cause I can see its location and I tried the test they ask after you download it and it was working fine
- Every time I try the jest command it says "bash: jest: command not found." I've seen others recommend ./node_modules/.bin/jest but that still didn't help even if I did use Sudo i still get "No such file or directory" even though i can see that there is a directory in that path.
- I tried npm test and I get an error regarding a package.json
- I saw someone recommend to remove jest and install again with npm install -g jest command but that lead to a series of error about EACCES: permission denied.
- I thought it may have to do w my node version but it's 10.16.0 so I don't think its that.

Honestly, I feel like I'm all over the place tryna figure out why this is happening so any suggestion/help would be appreciated

other "solutions" I've tried are:
node_modules/jest/bin/jest reversestring/test.js --watch 
./node_modules/.bin/jest steps/test.js --watch

note: revesersestring and steps were exercises I was trying to run jest on

My OS is MAC

Comment: Did you install it globally with the -g option to npm?

Comment: Is the x flag present on the binary? If not, it isn’t executable.

Comment: @Mark I did install it globally

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how would I check that?

Comment: Can you please post your package.json

Comment: Maybe try sudo npm install -g jest

Comment: Hey.  That appears to be the package.json for you Jest library.  Can you post the package.json for your project instead.

Comment: I fixed the issue! npm run jest was the solution! thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 9):

The jest library must be installed globally.
Otherwise you need to run it from the absolute path in your `node_modules` folder.
The easiest way to run the jest command is to run an npm script. Like below:

`npm test`

you can install the jest-cli globally by running:

`npm install -g jest-cli`

Comment: I tried npm install --save-dev jest-cli in the folder I was working in and it gave me warnings but went through. When I go to use the jest command tho I still get the same issue :(

Comment: Can you please post your package.json

Comment: @Kaiaya add `-g` to the proposed command if you want to be able to  execute it from any location, not just the folder with your `package.json` in it. You might also have to adjust your `PATH` to include the `bin` directory for globally installed `npm` packages.

Answer (score 2):

Running:

```
npm install --save-dev jest-cli
```

Will put the jest command into the directory:

```
node_modules/.bin/
```

This directory is what is used to run commands via `package.json`

For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest -i"
},
```

Will be runnable via:

```
npm run test
```

Or:

```
yarn test
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by using `Jest Runner` extension in VSC.